# How do i insert checkbox values from a form into the database using PDO. I've tried doing something, but that doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey guys i want to insert the values of checkboxes from a form into a database. But what i tried is not working. I'm totally confused of how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML PART:

```
<div id="reg-data"></div>
<input type="text" name="username" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name" id="username" />
<div id="username_availability_result"></div>
<input type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="Enter your password" id="password" />
<label for="gender">Gender </label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required" id="gender" value="Male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required" id="gender" value="Female"/>Female
<br/><br/>
<label for="qualification">Qualification</label>
<select name="qualification" value="Qualification" id="qualification">
<option value="SSLC">SSLC</option>
<option value="HSC">HSC</option>
<option value="UG">UG</option>
<option value="PG">PG</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<label for="hobbies">Hobbies </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobbies" value="Cricket" />Cricket
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobbies" value="Music" />Music
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobbies" value="Swimming" />Swimming
<input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Please give your location" id="location" />
<input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Where do you work?" id="company" />
<input type="text" name="designation" placeholder="Provide your designation" id="designation" />

<div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" id="reg" disabled="disabled" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

PHP PART:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try
{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=test", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$qualification = $_POST['qualification'];
$hobb = array('cricket', 'music', 'swimming');
$hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
$sql = "Insert into lousers (Username, Password, Gender, Qualification, Location, Company, Designation) 
        values ('".$_POST["username"]."', '".$_POST["password"]."', '".$_POST["gender"]."', '".$_POST["qualification"]."', '".$_POST["location"]."', '".$_POST["company"]."', '".$_POST["designation"]."')";
$conn->exec($sql);
$id = $sql_insert_id;
$values = array();
foreach($hobb as $selection) {
    if(in_array($selection, $hobbies)) {
        $values[ $selection ] = 1;
    } else {
        $values[ $selection ] = 0;
    }
}
$s2 = "UPDATE 'lousers'.'join'
        SET
        'cricket' = '".$values['cricket']."',
        'music' = '".$values['music']."',
        'swimming' = '".$values['swimming']."'
        WHERE
        'join'.'id' = ".$id."";
  $conn->exec($s2);
   echo "<br>";
   echo 'Thank you for registering. Login to access your profile';
 ?>
```

Comment: You should use prepared statement, for preventing sql injection.

Comment: is this really a minimal example? be more specific then "doesn't work". (what is the error message, ...)

Comment: Yes i will. I would like to know how am i supposed to insert those multiple values. I've tried every other way. But dint work. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your full code or not, but in additional to using prepared statements, you should also really validate the user input first before attempting to insert it into the database.

Comment: @brett Yes. This is not my complete code. I have just pasted the part which is not working. Rest all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should really switch to prepared statements to get rid of the sql injection hole you have now.

Your current problem seems to be the use of the wrong kind of quotes:

```
$s2 = "UPDATE 'lousers'.'join'
    SET
    'cricket' = '".$values['cricket']."',
    'music' = '".$values['music']."',
    'swimming' = '".$values['swimming']."'
    WHERE
    'join'.'id' = ".$id."";
```

Single or double quotes are used for string values. For table- and column names you need to use backticks (`). That is only necessary if the name is a reserved word, starts with a number, contains spaces, etc., see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) for more details.

So it would look something like (using prepared statement placeholders although that is more urgent in your first sql statement):

```
$s2 = "UPDATE `lousers`.`join`
    SET
    `cricket` = :cricket,
    `music` = :music,
    `swimming` = :swimming
    WHERE
    `join`.`id` = :id;
```

Also note that html ID values need to be unique but that is not related to your current problem.

Comment: I've changed everything like you've told above. I'm getting this error. "Notice: Undefined variable: sql_insert_id in E:\xampp\htdocs\Log\register.php on line 19

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\Log\register.php on line 22

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\Log\register.php on line 22"

Comment: And also this error. "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\Log\register.php on line 22
Fill in all the fieldsSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':cricket, `music` = :music, `swimming` = :swimming WHERE `join`.' at line 3"